# How to improve performance android layout render

Tags: android, performance, templates, layout, render

My android app has 8 template layouts.

They are difference style like weight, number of string's line, have an icon?

It always changes screen.

It start with inflate template layout all 8 layouts.

```
view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_1, null);
view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_2, null);
.
.
.
view8 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_8, null);
```

and map all component

```
layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutID);
line1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.line1ID);
line2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.line2ID);
icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconID);
```

My code is checking what is the name of template.

example

template 1

then add view1 to mainframe

and config all components

```
icon.setImageDrawable(....);
line1.setText(....);
line2.setText(....);
layout.setBackgroundColor(....);
```

These're all my steps.

1. create all templates and map id
2. check template and choose
3. config all component
4. add to main frame

when swipe to next page

1. check template and choose
2. config all component
3. add to main frame

looping....

It's work OK if I slide to next page normally.
but it delay when I slide to next page quickly.

Are there better solution to config and render new page.

I am a newbie in android programming.
And sorry about my English.

Thank you

Comment: Which class are you using for paging? With `ViewPager` you can preload far neighbor pages via `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(int preloadPageCount)` and thus shorten the loading time.

Comment: just new xml file

<?xml .....
<RelativeLayout.....

......
</RelativeLayout>